# No funciona toggler y se cae en tamaños pequeños

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño sitio web para una inmobiliaria familiar que tenemos.

Tengo un gran problema con el navbar responsive de Bootstrap 5.1.3.

El caso es que el toggler (hamburguesa) no funciona. El navbar en sí no se oculta cuando esta debajo de 500px. Cuando se hace click en él, en algunos casos se retrae y en menos de 0.5 segundos se vuelve a extender y en otros casos no hace nada.

(En Desktop sí funciona bien, solo en tamaños pequeños pasa este problema)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en tamaños de dispositivos de 500px para abajo aproximadamente, se cae hacia abajo el toggler y el navbar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```css
body {
background: green !important;
}

.body_esp nav {
  /*background-color: #679708;
        background-color: -webkit-gradient(
            linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(50,50,50,0.8)),
            to(rgba(80,80,80,0.2)), color-stop(.5,#333333);*/
  background: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.020045518207282953) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Logo brand */

.body_esp nav .navbar-brand img {
  width: 38%;
}


/* Links (Fuente: Open Sans, Color: blanco)*/

.body_esp nav .in-navbar-lists_links {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 97%;
}

.body_esp nav .in-navbar-lists_links a {
  color: white !important;
}

.body_esp nav .in-navbar-lists_links #LoteamientosDropdown-cont a {
  color: #678a21 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap 5.1.3 -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Metadata -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body class="body_esp">
  <!-- Nav -->
  <div id="nav-s-carousel" style="position: relative">
    <!-- para que esten sobrepuestos :) -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="assets/img/nav/DF-logonormalblanco2png.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#InmoNav" aria-controls="InmoNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex align-items-end flex-column bd-highlight" id="InmoNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav p-2 bd-highlight  in-navbar-lists_links">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>&nbsp;Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="nosotros.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i>&nbsp;Nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="loteamientos.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-seedling"></i>&nbsp;Loteamientos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="contacto.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;Contacto</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @padaleiana listo, ya agregué el snippet.

Comment: @padaleiana Estoy usando el bundle de Bootstrap 5.1.3 en local

Comment: En el código veo que `data-bs-target` es un elemento con id _navbarNav_. ¿Está presente ese elemento con ese id?

Comment: @padaleiana En mi código local si, pero este código que copie y pegué acá lo hice antes de hacer ese cambio en el archivo original

Comment: Ahora lo añadí, el menú parece que se va a contraer pero en menos de 1 segundo se vuelve a desplegar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema radica en que estás agregando la clase *d-flex* al `div` que envuelve a la lista (`ul`).

Al mover las clases *d-flex* y *align-items-end*  al `ul`, no se tiene ese comportamiento errático.

Además, al eliminar la clase *flex-column*, se evita que aparezca en modo columna en *desktop*. En su lugar, en el `div` que envuelve al `ul` se agregaron las clases `me-auto`y `mb-lg-0`, [tal como describe la documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors).

```css
body {
  background: green !important;
}

.body_esp nav {
  /*background-color: #679708;
        background-color: -webkit-gradient(
            linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(50,50,50,0.8)),
            to(rgba(80,80,80,0.2)), color-stop(.5,#333333);*/
  background: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.020045518207282953) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56) 55%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Logo brand */

.body_esp nav .navbar-brand img {
  width: 38%;
}


/* Links (Fuente: Open Sans, Color: blanco)*/

.body_esp nav .in-navbar-lists_links {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 97%;
}

.body_esp nav .in-navbar-lists_links a {
  color: white !important;
}

.body_esp nav .in-navbar-lists_links #LoteamientosDropdown-cont a {
  color: #678a21 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap 5.1.3 -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Metadata -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body class="body_esp">
  <!-- Nav -->
  <div id="nav-s-carousel" style="position: relative">
    <!-- para que esten sobrepuestos :) -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="assets/img/nav/DF-logonormalblanco2png.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#InmoNav" aria-controls="InmoNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse me-auto mb-lg-0  bd-highlight" id="InmoNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav p-2 bd-highlight  in-navbar-lists_links d-flex align-items-end ">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>&nbsp;Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="nosotros.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i>&nbsp;Nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="loteamientos.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-seedling"></i>&nbsp;Loteamientos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="contacto.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;Contacto</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: En desktop no funciona...

Comment: No se alinean en el medio del navbar y se alinea todo a la izquierda. Ejemplo [acá](https://imgur.com/a/F116zEX)

Comment: Gracias! me ayudaste muchisimo.